# Watchdog module does not notify of directory rename?

Tags: python, linux, inotify, python-watchdog

I need to monitor files, which are *sometimes* created by an unwieldy application in sub-subdirectories of a `logs/` directory:

```
logs/foo/per_process_dir/journal.log
```

My little daemon is written in Python and uses the [watchdog-module](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) to watch over the files (inotify is used by the module on Linux). I simply ask the module to monitor the `foo/` subdirectory (recursively) and it notifies me, whenever a journal is appended...

This all works but... The whole `logs/` directory is rotated, when the application is restarted -- and I'd like my daemon to notice this automatically so that there'd be no need to restart it too.

I expected to receive a "moved" event -- when `logs/` is renamed to `logs-Sunday/`, for example -- but it does not happen... The daemon is small currently and I loath having to enlarge it by adding the code for watching the `logs/` folder separately.

Is there some other way, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch renames of the `logs` directory, you will need to attach your observer to its parent directory.  That is, if your `logs` directory is actually `appname/logs`, then instead of calling, e.g.:

```py
observer.schedule(event_handler, 'appname/logs', recursive=True)
```

You would use:

```py
observer.schedule(event_handler, 'appname', recursive=True)
```

(And you will subsequently need to filter events and ignore those that are outside of the `logs` directory.)

---

This happens because your filesystem observer is attached to the `logs` directory. When you rename the `logs` directory, your observer continues to monitor it...under the new name. That is, the observer is attached to the inode, not to the path.